# how to get selected radio button from radiobuttonlist in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, textbox, radiobuttonlist

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I determine the SelectedValue of a RadioButtonList in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/579597/how-can-i-determine-the-selectedvalue-of-a-radiobuttonlist-in-javascript)

i want to get selected radio button from asp.net radiobuttonlist in javascript. In textbox onchange event i wrote codes below;

```
<asp:RadioButtonList CssClass="radioWithProperWrap"
                  ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server" CellPadding="0" 
            CellSpacing="0" RepeatColumns="2" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" 
                  >
            <asp:ListItem Value="1" Selected="True">Aylık Ödeyeceğim Taksite Göre</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="2">Toplam Alacağım Krediye Göre</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:RadioButtonList>
<asp:TextBox ID="TempTxtBox" runat="server" onchange="myFun()" ></asp:TextBox>
```

And the javascript;

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

    function myFun() {


        var deger = document.getElementById('<%=TempTxtBox.ClientID%>').value;
        var vade  = document.getElementById('<%=MaturitytxtBox.ClientID%>').value;


        var radioButtons = document.getElementsByName('<%=RadioButtonList1.ClientID%>');

        var radio = radioButtons.item(0).checked;

        alert(radio);

    }

</script>
```

It is not working..Anyone can help?

Comment: This is much easier with jquery.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/

Comment: @awright18 - Even assuming the OP can use jQuery, the `:selected` selector doesn't work on radio buttons. Did you mean `:checked`?

Comment: @nnnnnn I love how like the first line on the page explains that, yet they suggest it.........