# RadioButtonList selected value in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, radiobuttonlist

I just want to ask how can I select the value of my radiobuttonlist here is my code.

```
    function CheckRadioButton(rdbRemarks){
         document.getElementByID(rdbRemarks).SelectedValue = "1";
     }
```

Here is the code of my button onclick

```
<asp:Button ID="CheckRadioButton" CssClass="ButtonCalibri" Width="80px" runat="server" Text="Save" onclick="CheckRadioButton('<%=rdbRemarks.ClientID%>')" />
```

Here is the code of my radiobuttonlist in case you need a reference

```
    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rdbRemarks" CssClass="LabelCalibri" runat="server" onselectedindexchanged="rdbRemarks_SelectedIndexChanged">
<asp:ListItem Value="1" Text="Charge to Utilization"></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Value="2" Text="Charge to Operating Expense"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

What I want is when I click the button, one of the radio button in the list will be selected, for example the selected value is "1" the first radio button will be selected. I currently have no idea how to do that now, Please help me on this one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I determine the SelectedValue of a RadioButtonList in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/579597/how-can-i-determine-the-selectedvalue-of-a-radiobuttonlist-in-javascript)

Answer (score 5):

Get RadioButtonList Selected value using jQuery

```
var selectedVal=$("[id$='RadioButtonList1']").find(":checked").val();
```

Answer (score 4):

In your `button click` event 
Inside your script

```
document.getElementById("idofradiobutton").checked = true;
```

JQuery solution:

```
$("#idofradiobutton").prop("checked", true);
```

//....TAKE THE SELECTED VALUE OF RADIO BUTTON

```
var radiovalue= document.getElementById('idofradiobutton').value;




if (radiovalue=="1") {
 document.getElementById('idofcorespondingradiobutton').checked = true;
}
```

//if you are using radiobutton list then try this

```
function getCheckedRadio() {
  var radioButtons = document.getElementsByName("IDofRadiobuttonlist");
  for (var x = 0; x < radioButtons.length; x ++) {
    if (radioButtons[x].checked) {
      alert("You checked " + radioButtons[x].id + " which has the value " + radioButtons[x].value);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What i want is to check the selected value. for example selected value is equals to "1" this <asp:ListItem Value="1" Text="Charge to Utilization"></asp:ListItem> should be checked.

Comment: You mean if selected value is 1 then you want to check the radio button ? am i right ?

Comment: Yes that's what i mean.

Comment: Ok check my updated answer , now var radiovalue hold the selected value of radio button , and then you can use that value in condition and you can check the radio button what did you want .

Comment: I did that, now what will code will I right to check the selected value? That's my question, i didn't know the code.

Comment: for checking selected value od a radiobutton you can use var variablename=document.getElementById('idofradiobutton').value;

Comment: You don't get me my question is, what code will i right here
if(radiovalue=="1"){what is the code}

Comment: check the answer, if you know the id of radiobutton then inside the loop you can check the radiobutton

Comment: The id is on the radiobuttonlist itself, you can't put an ID on one of the radiobutton inside the radiobutton list.

Comment: so document.getElementById('idofcorespondingradiobutton').checked = true; is not an option.

Comment: sorry i did't notice you are using radiobuttonlist , check my updated ans i think it will help you

Comment: I did it like this sir, look at my question above before seeing this.

var radioButtons = document.getElementsByName(sRemarks);
        for (var x = 0; x < radioButtons.length; x++) {
                retval.field9 = radioButtons[x].value
                if (radioButtons[x].value = "1") {
                    radioButtons[x].checked = true;
            }
        }

Comment: It's still not working, .length value is 0 when i'm debugging it.

Answer (score 2):

```
function Validation(){

var radioButtonlist=document.getElementById(<%=rdbdeductionList.ClientID%>");


    var inputs = radioButtonlist.getElementsByTagName('input');
    var flag = false;
    var selected;

    for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
        if (inputs[i].checked) {
                   selected = inputs[i];
                   flag = true;
                   break;
        }
    }


    if (flag) {

              alert(selected.value);
     }

    else {

         alert('Please select an option.!');
         return false;

        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try This**

```
 var elementRef = document.getElementById("rdbRemarks"); // ID of DropDown
 for (var i=0; i<elementRef.options.length; i++)
 {
     if ( elementRef.options[i].value == "1") // value you want to select 
     {
        elementRef.options[i].selected = true;   
     }
 }
```

**OR** (**JQuery**)

```
    var value = 1;
    $("input[id=rdbRemarks][value=" + value + "]").attr('checked', 'checked');
                                      //OR
    $("input[id=mygroup][value=" + value + "]").prop('checked', true);
```

Comment: @eeljon_i3 - glad to help you. if answer is useful for you - `accept`the answer and `upvote` it will helps other to find out the correct solutions.

Comment: thanks for the help, but it is not working. It still can't check the radio button i want to check.

Answer (score 0):

The selected value can be retrieved using JavaScript with the line below:

```
var selectedvalue = $('#<%= yourRadioButtonList.ClientID %> input:checked').val()
```